# How do you use optional and non optional arguments?

Tags: c, command-line

I understand how to use getopt to accept command-line arguments like

`./program -a yes -b no`

What I am currently trying to do is accept command-line arguments where some are optional and some are not.

For example:

```
./program argv[1] argv[2] -a yes -b no
```

Answer (score 0):

Options after multiple optional arguments is probably bad idea; don't design the command line syntax that way, if you can help it.

That said, you can parse the arguments yourself outside of `getopt` until you see something which looks like an option (while incrementing `argv` and decrementing `argc`). Then use `getopt` for the remainder of the command line from that point on.

Pseudo-code:

```
for (; *argv; argc--, argv++) {
  if (argv looks like an option)
    break;

  process *argv somehow      
}

now process with getopt(argc, argv, ...)
```